# Method for Using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton, pdo

So I've found a method which looked nice to me: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php#97682

Requires PHP 5.3 but my host only supports 5.2 :(

So what method should I use for PDO, where it only connects to the database when needed?
And reuses the same connection?

Comment: maybe you should also change a title? PDO is perfectly usable in php 5.2 ;)

Comment: Are you using a particular programming method, e.g. MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a procedural singleton for readability:

```
 function db() {
      static $conn;
      if (!isset($conn)) {
           $conn = new PDO("sqlite:/tmp/db");
      }
      return $conn;
 }
```

This simplifies the use to for example:

```
 $rows = db()->query("SELECT * FROM all")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Interesting, does making $conn static allow it to be used for all calls of db()?

Comment: The static is just there so the function doesn't "forget" the set variable. So the $conn is instantiated really just once, and remains active for all consecutive calls of db().

Answer (score 1):

you can use singleton with instance. Database::getInstance() which creates, caches and returns PDO object

Comment: How would I do that? I'm new to singleton.

Comment: look at mario's response, its quite straightforward. Singleton using class is quite similiar, you have just a little more typing

Answer (score 0):

```
class db{

   protected static $conn;
   public static function getInstance() {

      if (!isset(self::$conn)) {
           self::$conn = new PDO("sqlite:/tmp/db");
      }

      return self::$conn;
   }
 }

$rows = db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM all")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess procedural looks nicer.